# Blender 2.8 Texture Brush "Draw" doesn't paint

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I am getting started on Texture Painting in Blender. I unwrapped my model, everything shows up nicely in the Texture Paint mode.

The weird thing is even though the paint bucket and smudge tool work fine, the brush just won't draw anything.

I already turned off pressure sensitivity, set the strength up and tried different stroke modes, but nothing happens.

Has anyone got ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Double check that you haven't got a Brush Texture that is just an Image Texture with black - that sometimes happens by accident and it will prevent you from painting anything until you delete the link to that brush texture.